# Cannot convert from string to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use Datetime Picker to get range of dates and then display in a Report viewer, having added the controls, its thrwoing back an error on the Date From and Date To Field.

My code Looks Like this , I am Using MetroUI framework for C# winform

```
this.visit_dbTableAdapter.Fill(this.VisitDateSet.visit_db,dateFrom.Text,dateTo.Text);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

having renamed dateFrom and dateTo are already named.

The error it gives back looks like this

```
Cannot convert from string to System.DateTime
```

Comment: It sounds like `.Fill()` wants a DateTime object rather than a string representation of time, have you tried `.Fill(this.VisitDateSet.visit_db, DateTime.Parse(dateFrom.Text), DateTime.Parse(dateTo.Text));`?

Comment: @Equalsk, Thanks This Works! what DateTime.Parse() can do

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` will take a string and attempt to convert it into an actual DateTime as long as the machine it's running on has the appropriate culture. Put it into your favourite search engine, there are lots of guides...

Answer (score 2):

Do the following change

```
this.visit_dbTableAdapter.Fill(this.VisitDateSet.visit_db,Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom.Text.Trim()),Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text.Trim()));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

*Putting Text directly in place of `DateTime` values will generally throws an error, As the `.Fill` method expects `DateTime` values as that were your columns `DataType` in Database.*

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I always love that people are eager for answers, but not so eager to vote and mark as answer :)